# Help with a showing the difference of bases in different topologies.

Tags: general-topology

I am currently practicing for my final exam in general topology, and I wish to verify if my attempt to this problem is correct.

Question: Show that the collection
$ C = \{[a,b)\; |\; a<b, \text{ $a$ and $b$ rational} \}$
is a basis that generates a topology different from the lower limit topology on $\mathbb{R}_l$

My attempt: Given that 
$$\mathbb{R}_l = \{[a,b)\; |\; a<b, \text{ with } a,b\in\mathbb{R} \}$$

$$  \;\;\;\;\;\;\; \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;= \{[a,b)\; |\; a<b, \text{ $a$ and $b$ rational} \} \cup \{[a,b)\; |\; a<b, \text{ $a$ and $b$ irrational} \}$$

$$\mathbb{R}_l = C \cup \{[a,b)\; |\; a<b, \text{ $a$ and $b$ irrational} \}$$

we have that for a given basis $S\subset C$ that $S\subset R_l$. In other words, the topology generated by $\mathbb{R}_l$ is strictly finer than the topology generated by $C$, and therefore the topology generated by $C$ is different that of $\mathbb{R}_l$.

Comment: You missed two cases:  a is rational, b is irrational and a is irrational, b is rational.

Comment: The fact that $C$ is a proper subset of $R_l$ does not by itself imply that $C$ and $R_l$ do not generate the same topology....For example $A=\{(a,b): a.b\in \Bbb Q\}$  is a proper subset of $B=\{(a,b): a,b\in \Bbb R\} $  but both $A$ and $B$ are bases for the usual (standard) topology on  $\Bbb R.$.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there are also intervals like $[a,b)$ where $a$ is irrational and $b$ is rational (so you don’t cover all the possibilities).

Secondly the base is almost always smaller than the topology it generates: all $(a,b)$ with $a,b$ rational do generate *all* open intervals (and unions of those), so the fact that the set $\mathcal{B} = \{[a,b): a,b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ is smaller than the whole standard base of $\mathbb{R}_l$ in itself proves nothing.

The actual argument could be that the topology generated by $\mathcal{B}$ is by definition second countable but $\mathbb{R}_l$ is not. (Lots of proofs of this can be found on this site and online elsewhere.) So the topologies are very different. So $\mathcal{B}$ generates a topology strictly in between the usual topology and the Sorgenfrey (lower limit) topology, and this intermediate topology is zero-dimensional and metrisable, by Urysohn.

Answer (score 1):

If $x\in \Bbb R$ \ $\Bbb Q$  then $[x,x+1)$ is open in the lower-limit topology (a.k.a. the Sorgenfrey Line).  But if $x\in U$ where $U$ is in the topology generated by  $C$ then $x\in [a,b)\subset U$ for some $a,b\in \Bbb Q.$ This implies   that the non-empty set $[a,x)\subset U,$ so $U\ne [x,x+1).$ So $[x,x+1)$ does not belong to the topology generated by $C.$

Answer (score 0):

$[\pi,4)$ is in the lower limit topology but not in the other.